# Remove duplicates from NSMutableArray based on an object's property

Tags: ios, duplicates, nsmutablearray

I have this NSMutableArray, containing a Message object. Message has several properties, one of them is TheID.

So, consider the following objects in my array:

```
Message1.TheID = 1
Message1.title = @"whatever"

Message2.TheID = 2
Message2.title = @"doesn't matter"

Message3.TheID = 1
Message3.title = @"I don't care"
```

I want to get rid of duplicate TheIDs.

What would be the best way to filter my array in such a way, that I end up with an array containing Message1 and Message2 (or Message2 and Message3)

I've seen many similar questions, but none of the solutions seem to be applicable to my situation.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `NSSet` to keep track of the used ids as you iterate through your message array. Only add a message to the new array of its id isn't in the set.

```
NSMutableSet *ids = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray *newMessages = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Message *message in messagesArray) {
    if (![ids containsObject:message.theID]) {
        [ids addObject:message.TheID];
        [newMessages addObject:message];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The only complication is, that TheID is an int (not an object). I will use another unique property though.

Comment: You can use the id. Just wrap it in an NSNumber before using it with the NSSet.